# PostgreSQL 9.3: Хочу совместить encode и substring

Tags: postgresql

Суть: Есть переменная, значение которой, скажем, "0x32303137303531323038303434372e35393422" (текстовое). Это двоично-десятичное представление, где содержится время события.

Есть функция encode, которая это значение преобразует в дату, если убрать 0 спереди и "22" сзади с помощью substring:

```
postgres=# select substring('0x32303137303531323038303434372e35393422' from 2 for 37);
substring
---------------------------------------
 x32303137303432383136303230332e353331
```

Преобразуем:

```
postgres=# select encode(E'\\x32303137303531323038303434372e353934', 'escape');
encode
--------------------
20170512080447.594
(1 row)
```

Теперь мне надо совместить две операции в одну. И не получается с синтаксисом:

```
select encode(E'\substring(\'0x2303137303531323038303434372e353934\' from 2 for 37)'::bytea,'escape');
encode
------------------------------------------------------------------
substring('0x2303137303531323038303434372e353934' from 2 for 37)
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Как нужно правильно сцепить Substring и Encode и можно ли это делать в принципе?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Приведение к типу bytea автоматически может выполнять ту же операцию, что и encode с escape. Но строка должна явно начинаться на `\x` что бы формат был распознан.

```
select ('\'||substring('0x32303137303531323038303434372e35393422' from 2 for 37))::bytea
```

Если тип возвращаемых данных должен быть text, как возвращает его encode, то можно все выражение указанное выше заключить в скобки и привести тип еще раз как `(...)::text`.

Comment: Mike, спасибо! Можете подсказать а при записи в базу, как можно сделать так, чтобы в данные при INSERT отображались бы сразу в удобном виде? Ваш вариант работает, мне просто надо понять, можно ли сразу писать в удобочитаемом виде, или же при выводе сведений преобразовывать тип содержимого.

Comment: @Pavel А доступ к коду, который делает insert есть ? если да, то применять собственно это же приведение в самом insert и в бд хранить уже в готовом виде или вообще перейти на какой нибудь timestamp

Comment: я вожусь с Freeradius (доступ, естественно, есть), в частности, из аттрибута вида `0x00045915a39c2020203332353539302b3033303030300096f46b000200012020203332353539302b3033303030300324d25c32303137303531323134353935332e3532330000000880000400` я "выкусываю" нужный мне кусочек с датой и в том же INSERT вставляю в базу.

Comment: я получил ответ на свои вопросы. Еще раз спасибо вам!